# Stub dependent objects

Tags: class, rspec

Suppose that we have an object that has a vertical dependency from another

```
class Ship
  def initialize
    ...
  end

  def launch
    ShipLauncher.new(self, platform: platform)
  end
end


class ShipLauncher
  def initialize(ship, platform:)
  ...
  end
end
```

And we want to test it:

```
it do
  allow(ShipLauncher).to receive(:new)

  ship = Ship.new
  ship.launch

  expect(ShipLauncher).to have_received(:new).with(ship, platform: 'x')
end
```

Until now all seems good, but if we change the ShipLauncher class like this

```
 class ShipLauncher
  def initialize(ship, platform_number:)
  ...
  end
end
```

The test will pass when it shouldn't because the ShipLauncher class expects another parameter. What I'm doing wrong? I must test it with an integration test? What happen if the ShipLauncher class hides a big complexity? I have to stub all its dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a feature called ["partial doubles"](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/verifying-doubles/partial-doubles) that can be used to check for this.

First, you need to enable it:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Then write your spec like this:

```
describe Ship do
  it "launches a ship" do
    ship = Ship.new
    expect(ShipLauncher).to receive(:new).with(ship, platform: 'x')

    ship.launch
  end 
end
```

This will pass with the original code:

```
> rspec ship_spec.rb  
.

Finished in 0.00429 seconds (files took 0.19664 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Now, make the change:

```
class ShipLauncher
  def initialize(ship, platform_number:)
    ...
  end
end
```

And you will get this error:

```
rspec ship_spec.rb  
F

Failures:

  1) Ship should receive new
     Failure/Error: expect(ShipLauncher).to receive(:new).with(ship, platform: 'x')
       Missing required keyword arguments: platform_number
     # ./ship_spec.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00437 seconds (files took 0.2022 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Note that the spec is *not* actually calling the `initialize` method on `ShipLauncher`, which you can verify:

```
class ShipLauncher
  def initialize(ship, platform_number:)
    raise Exception, "This code should not be run!"
  end
end
```

Run the spec, and you'll get the same results in both cases. The partial double is simply checking that the arguments and method names match the object being mocked out.